# Is it possible to change content of html <input> file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

My website require user upload their xml file with specify format.
So I want do a syntax and format check on client side, and help them fix those error before upload to server. (I do not require change the real local file on hard drive, only need change the data send to server)
I currently use:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var xml = e.target.result;
  // I help them correct xml here, this will involve lots of interaction with user,
  // so I want it only happen on client side
  var correctXML = fixSyntaxAndFormat(xml);  
  $.post('/foo/bar', {xml: correctXML});
}
reader.readAsText(evt.target.files[0]);
```

This code works, except it send xml in post data instead of a real uploaded file.
Because I want monitor file upload progress and save other file information, so I hope can have something like: `oldfile.content = correctXML`
then I can just submit that form which contain my `<input type="file"/>`.
Is this possible to do ? Or is there a "correct" way to do this?

Thanks

**Update**
Thanks for austincheney's example, I end up with create `new Blob()` and use this replace the original file. Seems work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is entirely possible, and it is typically used to assist with drag and drop file operations.  For instance if you want users to be able to drop files onto a textarea you can make the textarea a drop zone where the path the files is fed silently to the input type file element.  I do this on my own site.

Checkout the function pd.file and pd.filedrop in http://prettydiff.com/pd.js and demo the result on my tool at http://prettydiff.com/